# calling a REST service from jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, rest

I have created a REST service at `"/post/search/{id}"` and when I call this URL from my jquery code sometimes it gets called sometimes not. What is the exact problem in it. Is it regarding jquery or my code. My jquery code is as follows:

```
    function functionname(clicked_id) {
     $('#idForm').submit(
            function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/post/search/"+ clicked_id,success : function(data) {

                }
            });
        });
}
```

My button code is :

```
<input type="submit" value="Express Intrest" id="abc" onclick=functionname(this.id) />
```

Comment: is the ` actually in your code or was it a typo?

Comment: is special character ` present in your code or by mistake you have included it here?

Comment: @Michael @ Sumit Chourasia it ws included by mistake not present in my original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this.

```
function yourFunc() {


    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'yourcontroller/action',
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : param,
        async : false,
        cache: false,
        success : function(dataList) {
            //alert("dataList ---> "+dataList); 



        },

        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(XMLHttpRequest + " - " + errorThrown);
        }
    });


}
```

pass parameter values in param like this :-

```
var param;      
    param={param1:"val",param2:"val", param3:"val"};
```

Comment: @ Sumit Chourasia I am using POST method can I replace your type : 'GET', with type : 'POST', Sorry for stupid question I don't know anything about jquery/ajax.

Comment: yes sure , use the same whatever you are using in your code behind.

Comment: I've changed 'GET' to 'POST', now try this one, it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

change your button type from submit to button.

Because when you click on button your page start submitting.so the ajax function is sometime completed not completed before page.

```
   <input type="button" value="Express Intrest" id="abc" onclick=functionname(this.id) />
```